# Want to show url like termname (parent)/[termname] (Child: referenced by node) /node (node which is referenced to particular term)

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Having problem to show url like termname (parent)/[termname] (Child: referenced by node) /node (node which is referenced under particular term)

i want this http://www.example.com/pets/cats/diseases/4-normal-diseases-of-kittens

here **pets** is parent term name
cats is child of parent 'pets' term name
diseases again sub term name of 'cats'
'4-normal-diseases-of-kittens' is article term referenced to diseases

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In your URL aliases patterns, use this token : **[node:YOURTAXONOMYFIELD:parents-all]** (*Ancestors of the term, i.e. parent of all above hierarchy levels*).

Then your whole pattern for your node type will be [node:YOURTAXONOMYFIELD:parents-all]/[node:title].

If you have languages matters, I guess it might work with i18n prefix.

Comment: showing this error  : The Pattern for all Article Post paths is using the following invalid tokens: [node:field_topic:parents-all].

but if i use only [node:field_topic]/[node:title] works fine

Comment: Can you try [node:field-topics:parents-all] ?

Comment: Now using this [node:field-topics:1:parents-all]/[node:title]
but still article's url only showing one term(term referenced terms) not parent terms

Comment: Did you suppress and rebuild all your content paths ?

Comment: Yes its solved @Gregory, Thanks for your help
i used 
[node:field-topics:parents:join-path]/[node:field-topics:name]/[node:title]

Comment: @Somik Dont forget to mark this as the accepted answer if it helped solve the problem. You can do that by clicking the check mark icon next to the answer :)

Comment: @clive this helped but not solved, i solved it with some other way, thanks for directions clive

Comment: hey @clive it was really nice of you the way you explained, never got this kind of behaviour as a new comer, thanks a lot, may i have your skype or email id, mine was Skype: somik47